# Dealing with per-developer resources such as database.properties or log4j.properties in a java project

Tags: java, maven, resources, log4j

We are 4 developers working on a **maven-based java web project**. We each have a specific `database.properties` file that points to a per-developer database schema.

The problem we currently have is that **we sometimes inadvertently commit our per-developper database.properties or `log4j.properties`** files with the obvious issue that this causes.

On the other hand, if we drop those files into the `/lib` directory of Tomcat, we might forget to include them to the production application that gets shipped.

Can anyone please provide advice or suggest best practices in order to sort this problem?

Comment: Which version control tool are you using?

Comment: @Ilya: CVS but I was seeking guidance that could apply to several SCMs.

Comment: You can tell to CVS to ignore this files

Comment: Thanks Ilya. I am going to do that.

Comment: For the different dev/prod properties question search for maven profiles https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html and look this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325366/maven-different-property-files-for-different-profiles/8325803#8325803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start using [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and [Maven Resource Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) together.

If you combine these two techniques then each user could have his profile defined in the `%USER_HOME%/.m2/settings.xml` file while the `database.properties` and `log4j.properties` files use resource filtering to get the user specific properties from the user profile properties.

I've been using this technique to support different databases by setting up a structure like this:

```
src
  |-main
       |-filters
       |       |-derby.properties
       |       |-h2.properties
       |       |-mssql.properties
       |       |-mysql.properties
       |-templates
                 |-db.properties
```

And in my `pom.xml`

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>derby</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/derby.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/templates</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mysql</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/mysql.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/templates</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mssql</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/mssql.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/templates</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>h2</id>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/h2.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/templates</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You should be able to do the same thing with your files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Git and only push to the master when you clense the local references.