# how to perform task for different profiles using maven

Tags: java, maven-2

I am new to Maven.

I want to perform database connection for different users so my problem is that where I should provide this JDBC connection and how to provide this connection for different users?

I know how to provide profiles for different users but where should I perform database connection and how it get invoked?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "perform database connection"? Maven is a build tool, what is supposed to happen with data from the database during a maven build?

Comment: For what reason do you need to perform database connection? For your tests?

Comment: @Nicolas yes I want to perform for just tests like user name and password provide. so where should I do this I don't understand. please help me for that.

Comment: @f1sh I want to perform task by just setting configuration in net beans means I want to set different profiles for users and their database credentials so where should I perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach would make your database connection properties (like username/password, url, etc) external. Within a profile you could than define per user the values for the properties and use the maven resource filtering to set them.

Within your maven project you would for example have a config directory (in `src/config/settings.prp`) which for example contains the following entries:

```
userName = ${userName}
password = ${password}
db-driver = ${dbDriver}
db-url = ${dbUrl}
```

Within the pom you would have

```
<project ...>
    <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.7</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>filter-db-settings</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/config</outputDirectory>
                           <resources>
                               <resource>
                                   <directory>${project.basedir}/src/config</directory>
                               </resource>
                               <filtering>true</filtering>
                           </resources>
                       </configuration> 
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
        <plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>user-A</id>
            <properties>
                <userName>userA</userName>
                <password>secret</password>
                <dbDriver>com.driver.db</dbDriver>
                <dbUrl>jdbc://db-url</dbUrl>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    <profiles>
</project>
```

The plugin will filter the files in `src/config` and replace the maven placeholders by the values as specified within your profile. Since the profile contains a password you could move it to your `settings.xml` so that it is not checked in with the project itself possibly exposing the password to unwanted parties.

*WARNING:* Haven't verified the plugin above so might contain small mistakes.

Best practice it to put the property file *NOT* within the generated artifact. By doing this you get the freedom to use the same artifact fro different users and the only thing you need to change are the properties in the external property file, (which will be given to user beside the artifact).

The following article explains how you can externalize the properties with spring [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: Give me example for how can I write my pom.xml file for different users and how can I perform database related tasks for this specific user?

Comment: What do you mean by database related tasks?

Comment: This might also be useful: [maven different property files for different profiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325366/maven-different-property-files-for-different-profiles?rq=1)

Comment: that's the thing I want but now difficulty is to how I can run queries from pom.xml file only with retrieving properties file values?

Comment: You can influence that by having the filtering be done before the querying of the db from maven and that can be done by including the proper phase in the goal (so for example filtering resources at maven phase `process-resources` and the execution of sql queries at `test`). see [maven lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for the different lifecycles and how to define phase in execution.